# how to get only pure string after join 2 table

Tags: django, string, join

I had join 2 table together and it works fine as below

```
dictData["USER_ROLE"] = Group.objects.filter(user__id=dictData["USER"].id)
```

But dictData["USER_ROLE"] gives me a string of

```
 [<Group: Team Member>]
```

I only need " Team Member " What should I do??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a user can be only in one group, 
You can do:

```
dictData["USER_ROLE"] = Group.objects.filter(user__id=dictData["USER"].id)[0].name
```

`Group.objects.filter(user__id=dictData["USER"].id)` will give you QuerySet List. If the user has only one group, you can get it by it's 0th index.

```
Group.objects.filter(user__id=dictData["USER"].id)[0]
```

as you said: "I only need " Team Member " What should I do??"
Here Team Member is name of the group, So 
`Group.objects.filter(user__id=dictData["USER"].id)[0].name` will give you unicode string i.e.s "Team Member"

Answer (score 0):

You've queried for Group objects, so that's what you've got.

You can use `values_list` if you just need a single field:

```
Group.objects.filter(user__id=dictData["USER"].id).values_list('name', flat=True)
```

assuming the field is called "name".

Comment: Thank you for the solution but I got "  [(u'Team Member,)] ". what should I do to get only " Team Member "

Comment: Use `flat=True` to get a flat list.

Comment: I still get this " [u'Team Member'] "

Comment: Yes. That is correct, a list containing the values you want.

Comment: Sorry for asking too much question, I am a beginner of Django and have no idea how i can get only " Team Member" from  [u'Team Member'], could you please give me more information to get the value from the list.

Comment: But you need a list. You have a many-to-one relation, what happens when the user is in more than one group?

Comment: Ah! I see, thank you so much! Now I understand it and solve the problem ;))